# Query returning exact number of rows

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, postgresql-8.3

I have a table that stores two foreign keys, implementing a n:m relationship.

One of them points to a person (`subject`), the other one to a specific item.
Now, the amount of items a person may have is specified in a different table and I need a query which would return the same number of rows as the number of items a person may have.

The rest of the records may be filled with `NULL` values or whatever else.

It has proven to be a pain to solve this problem from the application side, so I've decided to try a different approach.

Edit:
Example

```
CREATE TABLE subject_items
(
  sub_item integer NOT NULL,
  sal_subject integer NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT pkey PRIMARY KEY (sub_item, sal_subject),
  CONSTRAINT fk1 FOREIGN KEY (sal_subject)
      REFERENCES subject (sub_id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT fk2 FOREIGN KEY (sub_item)
      REFERENCES item (item_id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
)
```

I need a query/function which would return all subject items (subject may have 5 items)
but there are only 3 items assigned to the subject.

Return would be somewhat like:

```
sub_item   |  sal_subject
2          |   1
3          |   1
4          |   1
NULL       |   1
NULL       |   1
```

I am using postgresql-8.3

Comment: Could not understand the situation. Can you give some table structures and desired output of the query?

Comment: Your return table at the end of the question must hold the value `1` in all rows for `sal_subject`, never `NULL`, to make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider this largely **simplified** version of your **plpgsql function**. Should work in PostgreSQL **8.3**:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION x.fnk_abonemento_nariai(_prm_item integer)
  RETURNS SETOF subject_items AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
    _kiek    integer :=  num_records    -- get number at declaration time
                         FROM subjekto_abonementai WHERE num_id = _prm_item;
    _counter integer;
BEGIN

RETURN QUERY                            -- get the records that actualy exist
SELECT sub_item, sal_subject
FROM   sal_subject 
WHERE  sub_item = prm_item;

GET DIAGNOSTICS _counter = ROW_COUNT;   -- save number of returned rows.

RETURN QUERY
SELECT NULL, NULL                       -- fill the rest with null values
FROM   generate_series(_counter + 1, _kiek);

END;
$BODY$ LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE STRICT;
```

Details about [plpgsql in the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/interactive/plpgsql.html) (link to version 8.3).

Comment: Thank you for your answers. As much as i liked the other method, i accept this one just because it's easier to read/modify.

Comment: @ertx: With pg 8.3 I would chose this one, too. Pure SQL is unwieldy without the `row_number()` window function in this case.

Comment: Also, i didn't knew variables may be assigned upon declaration by selecting. Very convenient.

Answer (score 2):

Could work like this (**pure SQL solution**):

```
SELECT a.sal_subject
     , b.sub_item
FROM  (
    SELECT generate_series(1, max_items) AS rn
         , sal_subject
    FROM   subject
    ) a
LEFT   JOIN (
    SELECT row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY sal_subject ORDER BY sub_item) AS rn
         , sal_subject
         , sub_item
    FROM   subject_items
    ) b USING (sal_subject, rn)
ORDER  BY sal_subject, rn
```

1. Generate the maximum rows per subject, let's call them theoretical items.
    See the manual for [`generate_series()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-srf.html).
2. Apply a row-number to existing items per subject.
    Manual about [window functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-window.html).
3. `LEFT JOIN` the existing items to the theoretical items per subject. Missing items are filled in with NULL.

In addition to the table you disclosed in the question, I assume a column that holds the maximum number of items in the `subject` table:

```
CREATE temp TABLE subject
( sal_subject integer,     -- primary key of subject
  max_items int);          -- max. number of items
```

---

Query for **PostgreSQL 8.3**, substituting for the missing window function `row_number()`:

```
SELECT a.sal_subject
     , b.sub_item
FROM  (
    SELECT generate_series(1, max_items) AS rn
         , sal_subject
    FROM   subject
    ) a
LEFT   JOIN (
    SELECT rn, sal_subject, arr[rn] AS sub_item
    FROM  (
        SELECT generate_series(1, ct) rn, sal_subject, arr
        FROM  (
            SELECT s.sal_subject
                 , s.ct
                 , ARRAY(
                        SELECT sub_item
                        FROM   subject_items s0
                        WHERE  s0.sal_subject = s.sal_subject
                        ORDER  BY sub_item
                    ) AS arr
            FROM  (
                SELECT sal_subject
                     , count(*) AS ct
                FROM   subject_items
                GROUP  BY 1
                ) s
            ) x
        ) y
    ) b USING (sal_subject, rn)
ORDER  BY sal_subject, rn
```

More about substituting `row_number()` in this [article by Quassnoi](http://explainextended.com/2009/05/11/postgresql-emulating-row_number/).

Comment: Your solution looks really nice but i probably should've mentioned i'm using 8.3.4 version and as far as i can see window functions only apply to 8.4+.

Comment: @ertx: Yup, you should definitely have mentioned that. Window functions are for PostgreSQL 8.4+. I added a solution for 8.3.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to come up to this simplistic solution:
First returning all the values i may select then looping returning null values while we have the right amount. Posting it here if someone would stumble on the same problem. 
Still looking for easier/faster solutions if they exist.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fnk_abonemento_nariai(prm_item integer)
  RETURNS SETOF subject_items AS
$BODY$DECLARE _kiek integer;
DECLARE _rec subject_items;
DECLARE _counter integer;
BEGIN
  /*get the number of records we need*/
  SELECT INTO _kiek num_records
  FROM subjekto_abonementai
    WHERE num_id = prm_item;

  /*get the records that actualy exist */

  FOR _rec IN SELECT sub_item, sal_subject
      FROM sal_subject 
      WHERE sub_item = prm_item LOOP
    return 
      next _rec;
    _counter := COALESCE(_counter, 0) + 1;
  END LOOP;

  /*fill the rest with null values*/

  While _kiek > _counter loop
    _rec.sub_item := NULL;
    _rec.sal_subject := NULL;
    Return next _rec;
    _counter := COALESCE(_counter, 0) + 1;
  end loop;

END;$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;
```

Comment: The clause `WHERE num_id = sub_item` in line 8 of the function body does not make sense.

Comment: Fixed, i've changed several things before posting here since this is just a part of a bigger structure.